# Pthread Synchronization with conditional variables

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, synchronization

I am practicing about pthread synchronization by using mutexes and conditional variable. In my below code, I create 3 threads, and I am expecting to see the output as telling which thread is executed and then exiting from the main thread as reporting the value of count. However, I observed that I can have 3 different outputs.
Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 
#include<pthread.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 


typedef struct node{

    int data;
    struct node* next;

}LinkList;

LinkList *list = NULL ;
//LinkList *head;
int count;
int enter;

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void* trythis(void *arg) 
{ 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    //enter = 0;
    printf("Thread sleeps... \n");
    while(!enter){
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
    }
    enter = 1;
    printf("Thread %d Enter = %d\n",count++,enter);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL; 
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    pthread_t tid[3];
    int error;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Main Beginning1\n");
    int p = pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);

    if(p != 0){
        printf("Mutex failed \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Main Beginning2\n");
    while(i < 3) 
    { 
        error = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &trythis, NULL); 
        if (error != 0) 
            printf("\nThread can't be created : [%s]", strerror(error)); 
        i++; 
    } 
    printf("Main Beginning3\n");
    /*for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL); 
    }*/
    printf("Main Beginning4\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    enter = 1;
    printf("Main Beginning\n");
    while(count < 2){

        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
        printf("count : %d\n",count);
    }

    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    printf("Main count = %d\n",count);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);



    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

and my output is :

```
***FIRST OUTPUT***
oguzliv@oguzliv-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/OSindAir$ ./linklist 
Main Beginning1
Main Beginning2
Thread sleeps... 
Main Beginning3
Thread sleeps... 
Main Beginning4
Main Beginning
Thread sleeps... 
Thread 0 Enter = 1
Thread 1 Enter = 1
Thread 2 Enter = 1
count : 3
Main count = 3

***SECOND OUTPUT***
oguzliv@oguzliv-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/OSindAir$ ./linklist 
Main Beginning1
Main Beginning2
Thread sleeps... 
Main Beginning3
Main Beginning4
Main Beginning
Thread sleeps... 
Thread 0 Enter = 1
Thread sleeps... 
Thread 1 Enter = 1
count : 2
Main count = 2

***THIRD OUTPUT***
oguzliv@oguzliv-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/OSindAir$ ./linklist 
Main Beginning1
Main Beginning2
Thread sleeps... 
Thread sleeps... 
Main Beginning3
Main Beginning4
Thread sleeps... 
Main Beginning
(waits infinitely)
```

I don't know the reason of these outputs. Please help me. By the way, this code is independent from linklist struct.

------EDIT-----

After some research, I executed the code as I expected thanks to owner of this link https://gist.github.com/rtv/4989304

However, I am still confused about my previous code that why it does not execute as the edited one. All changed was :

```
while(!enter){
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&lock);
    }
    enter = 1;
    printf("Thread %d Enter = %d\n",count++,enter);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
```

to

```
const int myid = long(args);
printf("Thread sleeps with ID : %d\n",myid);
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
count++;
printf("Thread ID : %d count : %d",myid,count);
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

return NULL;
```

Comment: Please add an language tag like `C`. People who know the language pretty well often use the language tag to filter questions, so your question can be found and answered more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, your original code is racing on the value of enter.   Consider the two scenarios:

1. Your implementation gives priority to newly created threads.  So, as soon as pthread_create() is called, trythis() begins executing, grabs the mutex, discovers !enter, and waits for cond to be signalled. This happens for each thread.   Then main grabs the mutex, sets enter to 1, then waits for cond to be signalled.   Who will wake them up?  This type of synchronization failure used to be called intrigue, but the term has fallen out of usage.
2. Your implementation gives priority to the running thread.  So, pthread_create() constructs trythis(), but trythis doesn't begin executing yet.  When main is finished creating the threads, it grabs the mutex, sets enter to 1, then waits for cond to be signalled.   Since it is waiting (no longer running), the other threads start up, and each grab the mutex, discover enter is non-zero, so signal the condition, drop the mutex and exit.   One of them will wake up main, since it is the only thread waiting, and when it awakens it discovers that count is > 2, exits the loop as expected.

The real world can be an arbitrary blend of these, so you might find you leave 0..3 threads and/or main blocked.  The answer, I think, is that your line in main:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
enter = 1;
```

should have added:

```
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
```

That way, anybody who was already waiting on enter would be released.
From a flow perspective; "trythis" is consuming enter, and producing count; "main" is producing enter, and consuming count.